# Set Netbeans username

Tags: netbeans

How can I add a username to Netbeans where that name appears in JavaDoc of a JSF application as the Author. The following article describe how to do it, but it is quite outdated and navigation paths are entirely different to find a clue.

[Link to Old Article](http://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/customize-java-template.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tools > Template > Settings >>> Will Open an Editor

Uncomment Line and add the name like user=

(Following Link gives pictures but go through the comments to find the answer [Link](http://crypt-sdk.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-change-author-in-netbeans.html))